# Session variables sometimes stop working

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm currently using PHP to store some values (Session variables) and some game-logic functions, while the Javascript side is mostly for rendering and player's controls.

It worked fine before but a now the game started to crash and I realised that the Session's variables aren't showing the correct values, like they're updated late. The weird thing is this game works fine when running without "www" inside the url, and usually happens in the second round of the game. Below is the function that returns the wrong values when the game started to crash:

```
    function TakeCurrentTurn(){            
            $currentTurn = $_SESSION["CurrentTurn"];
            if ($currentTurn == $_SESSION["LastTurn"]){
                $_SESSION["LastTurn"] = 0;
            }

            if ($currentTurn == 1){
                OnPlayerMoved();
            }else{
                OnAiMoved();
            }

            if (GetSelectedCardCount($currentTurn) > 0){
                if (CsIsAllow($currentTurn) == true){
                    DrawSelectedCard();
                    $_SESSION["LastTurn"] = $currentTurn;
                }else{
                    UnselectAllCard($currentTurn);
                }
            }

            IncreaseCurrentTurn();        
            session_write_close();

            $img = [];
            $img[] = GetDeckImg(2);
            $img[] = GetDeckImg(3);
            $img[] = GetDeckImg(4);
            if ($_SESSION["LastTurn"] == $currentTurn && $currentTurn != 1 && $currentTurn != 0){
                $img4Count = count($img[2]);
                for ($i=0; $i<$img4Count; $i++){
                    $img[$currentTurn-2][] = $img[2][$i];
                }
            }

            echo implode(",", $img[0])." ".implode(",", $img[1])." ".implode(",", $img[2])." ".$currentTurn;
        }
```

The IncreaseCurrentTurn function increase the value of $_SESSION["CurrentTurn"] while the GetDeckImg function returns values from another Session variable.

When the whole thing crash, I noticed that the return values are showing the same values as the previous response. I'm not sure what can be causing this issue. I've placed the session_start() at the top of the file (below error_reporting(E_ALL)) and using session_write_close(), but doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Edit:

```
function IncreaseCurrentTurn(){
        $_SESSION["CurrentTurn"] += 1;
        if ($_SESSION["CurrentTurn"] > 3){
            $_SESSION["CurrentTurn"] = 1;
        }
    }

function GetDeckImg($player){
        $count = count($_SESSION["Poker"][$player]);
        $deck = [];

        for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
            $card = $_SESSION["Poker"][$player][$i];
            $deck[] = $card['img'];
        }
        return $deck;
    }
```

Edit2 (Updated Info):
After a number of more checking, I realised that the server was returning the previous result instead when the bug happened. When I resend the last request again, it will return the correct result (at the moment this is what I'm doing to handle the problem...). I also noticed that this problem only happened once (or never) per game, once I resend the last request and get the correct result, the rest of the game will run normally.

Comment: `www` is a subdomain. Just a guess: could it be that you are calling things without `www` inside your scripts? That would explain your behaviour: a cookie created from a subdomain is not automatically available for the domain itself (or other subdomains)

Comment: Can we see the function `IncreaseCurrentTurn()` and  `GetDeckImg()`? Additionally, try to clean up the code and logic. If nothing helps, `print_r($_SESSION);` in every function and see if the results are as expected. Smells like a logic error somewhere :-)

Comment: @Jan I've edited the question and putting the 2 functions in.

Comment: @Burki The javascript will use the same address as the page to contact the PHP side so if the user enters using 'www' the page also uses 'www' when contacting the PHP side.